# Cocos2d, rotated (transparent) sprite collision

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, collision-detection

Is there an inbuilt method that let's me detect intersection between two rotated sprites?

I know it's a second question, but is there (maybe) a pixel perfect detection method to exclude transparent parts of those two sprites?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe.
But there is also this:

> http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/12/fast-pixelperfect-collision-detection-cocos2d-code-1of2/
>
> Fast Pixel-Perfect Collision Detection for Cocos2D with Example Code (1/2)