# Cocos2d - Collision Detection of Rotated Sprite

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I try to detect collision between two sprite.

```
if(CGRectIntersectsRect([SpriteA BoundingBox], [SpriteB boundingBox]))
```

But when i Rotate any sprite than collision detection is not perfect..
I know to use pixel perfect Collision but i have no idea about it.
Please anyone help me for how to detect collision, Give me any block of code if any.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cocos2d, rotated (transparent) sprite collision](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887128/cocos2d-rotated-transparent-sprite-collision)

Answer (score 1):

You can use box2d to make it detect all collisions for you

Answer (score 1):

In two ways you can do.

1. Use box2D body for your sprite. Example: [CLICK HERE](http://www.raywenderlich.com/606/how-to-use-box2d-for-just-collision-detection-with-cocos2d-iphone)
2. Use CGMutablePathRef, and use CGPathContainsPoint() instead of CGRectIntersectsRect. 
   Example: [CLICK HERE](http://bobueland.com/cocos2d/2011/the-magic-of-cgpaths/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also refere the [Ray Wenderlich Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/606/how-to-use-box2d-for-just-collision-detection-with-cocos2d-iphone) for the detection of the Collision between any 2 Box2D bodies.

Answer (score 0):

it's possible! try with CGPath. 
I had the same problem. I've resolved with this tutorial: http://bobueland.com/cocos2d/2011/the-magic-of-cgpaths/

for rotate the path try this method, it rotated the path round the center of the boudingBox:

```
-(CGPathRef) rotateCGPath:(CGPathRef)path corner:(CGFloat)radians
{
    CGRect bounds = CGPathGetBoundingBox(path); 
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(bounds), CGRectGetMidY(bounds));
    CGAffineTransform transf = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    transf = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transf, center.x, center.y);
    transf = CGAffineTransformRotate(transf, -radians);
    transf = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transf, -center.x, -center.y);
    return CGPathCreateCopyByTransformingPath(path, &transf);
}
```

after this you detect the collision simple with:

```
if (CGPathContainsPoint(Collisionpath, NULL, collisionPoint, NO))
{ //is inside the path }
```

good luck!